# Why does my car's switched 12V drop to 5V when I add an accessory?

Tags: wiring, voltage

Disclaimer: I have very little electrical knowledge.

I have wired electronics (radar detectors, dash cameras, GPS units, etc.) to about a dozen vehicles in the past, but have ran into a strange issue with my 2016 Toyota Tacoma (which, I'm told, uses Can Bus).

I've found a switched 12V source (sensor on brake fluid reservoir); verified using a multimeter. 12v when the truck is running, 0 when it's off. I've spliced in a 12V accessory, and at this point the voltage dropped to 5V. If I disconnect my accessory's ground, the voltage goes back up to 12V.

I have tried numerous grounding locations for my accessory - does not seem to make a difference.

This appears to be the only easily-accessible, switched 12V source where I'm looking (engine bay), and I'd rather not run cables through the firewall to an in-cabin source.

What do I need to do in order to have my accessory run off this 12V source?

I'm guessing I could wire my accessory to the truck's battery via a relay, and use the switched 12V to control the relay, but I've never done that, so it's just a guess. I would prefer to avoid such complications, if possible.

Comment: Could you please provide more info on the switched 12v source?

Comment: @laptop2d - What kind of info are you looking for? It's a fluid-level sensor on the brake fluid reservoir. Two wires - 12V and ground.

Comment: Probably it is protected by some kind of electronic current limiting device, it is not just connected to 12V with wires.

Comment: Like how much current can you pull from it? How big are the wires? Have you tried powering the accessory with an external 12V source to make sure its not shorted?

Comment: Wiring diagram or schematic for your car shows what on that line?

Comment: I suggest that you keep away from breaking and other safety relevant wiring just for your peace of mind and future insurance liability possibilities.  The answer below is likely correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a wiring schematic for the vehicle. @laptop2d - I have tested this accessory (camera) with an external 12V battery and it's working fine. The sensor's wires are quite thin - I'd guess 20-22 gauge. It does sound like Marko Buršič's guess (limit on current) may be correct.

Comment: And why don't you tap the switched relay in the engine fuse box? An actual power line?

Comment: @Passerby - I looked in the relay box, but didn't see anything that instantly stood out as being a switched 12V. How would I go about finding one?

Comment: For the most part most of the relays are switched with the ignition on Acc. A wiring diagram is crucial, but you may want to try a specialty website forum like ***Tacomaworld*** or **ToyotaNation** to ask for specifics on which relay may be good to tap. Some of them have access to the 3rd Gen Tacoma service manuals. The Engine Main Relay comes to mind though.

Comment: I've had a lot of luck tapping into the "horn" circuit on several vehicles.  It's normally rated for relatively high current, and is almost always switched.  Try to honk the horn with your car off to make sure.

Comment: That's a good idea, @JPhi1618. A few folks on Tacomaworld suggested a couple other fuses too, so it sounds like there are some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did more research on this and the consensus seems to be that Tacoma's electronics detect the additional current (of the accessory), and drop the voltage automatically as some sort of safety/precaution mechanism. No alerts/lights/errors as a result of this, though.

I ended up using an add-a-circuit fuse tap to tap a switched fuse in the engine's fuse block.

Answer (score 8):

I think the comment reveals the problem: you've tapped a sensor wire on the brake fluid reservoir. Could it be that the 12V supply is routed through a red lamp on the dashboard that lights up when the sensor sees low level and connects the wire to ground? If that's the case, it would measure as 12V on the multimeter, via the un-lit bulb (low resistance). Your accessory draws some current (to ground) via the bulb and the voltage drops to 5V. Maybe the bulb glows dimly on the dashboard. The multimeter does not draw enough current (almost none at all) to light the bulb or to drop any voltage across it.

I think you'll need to find another place to tap off a switched 12V supply.

Comment: Thanks, John Honniball. Interestingly, disconnecting the sensor altogether does not trigger any lights or warnings on the car. Perhaps I need to actually drive it with the sensor disconnected in order for that to happen (I've only been running it while parked). Also, I've encountered exactly the same 12V->5V drop with another switched 12V wire in the dome-light area (I was wiring other accessories, and ended up connecting them to a different switched 12V in the same area - which worked as expected).

Comment: It could very well be that the sensor in the brake fluid reservoir connects its 12 volt input to ground when fluid is low and that connection triggers the alarm/turns on the dash lamp.  To check if that's the case, connect your accessory again (since it doesn't seem to hurt anything) and look to see if the warning lamp comes on.